# Jquery select first letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, query-string

I am simply attempting to get jquery to identify the first letter of a paragraph.  How would I do this?

For example, I have a page with a number of paragrahs on a page. I would like only the paragraphs starting with a specified letter to be given the class "current" and all others to be hidden.  I pretty much know how to add the class and hide the others but, I cant get jquery to recognize the first letter.

**Secondly, is it possible to pull this 'first letter' variable from the url string?**

For example,
Page 1 - There is a list of letters.  The user clicks 'B' and the url is

http://domain.com/page2.html?letter=b

And page2 picks up that variable (b) and applies it to the Jquery, showing only those paragraphs

Comment: Will you be using a server-side language like PHP to retrieve `$_GET['letter']`, or do you want to do this with jQuery as well?

Comment: It really doesnt matter to me either way.  I'm not opposed at all to working with some PHP as well.

Comment: I updated my answer in case you choose to handle it with client-side code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery('p').each(function(){     
    if(jQuery(this).text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() == 'B'){
         jQuery(this).addClass('someclass')
    }
   })
```

You can use PHP to clean the variable and the print it in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var letter = '<?php  echo (strlen($_GET['letter']) == 1) ? $_GET['letter'] : ''; ?>'
</script>
```

Or just grab it with `document.location` and extract it.

Comment: Remove the `if`. The `if` keyword is not present in a ternary operator.

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks for the pointer.  I have removed the If and it is now pulling the letter from the string. However the variable doesnt seem to be populating in the jquery.

Comment: Yah, sorry about that I had a full `if` statement and just grabbed it. 

@batfan, if  `var letter` is defined in the global space (outside a function), it should be accessible to the function by just using `if(jQuery(this).text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() == letter){`.

Comment: Though, you might be better off just grabbing it with JS.

Comment: @Aaron - Thanks for that.  It still wasnt working after I changed that but, then I tried changing the letter in the string from 'b' to 'B' and it worked.  Does it have to be in caps?  Also, it only displays the first paragraph that matches this letter.  How do I get it to show all matches?

Comment: It is better to set both the input and the match to uppercase (or lower case) you can change the PHP to include `strtoupper($_GET['letter'])` to force both to be uppercase in case the user changes it from one to the other. As far as I can tell, it works for all `<p>` tags.

Comment: @Aaron - Im checking the page using Firebug and it looks like the class "current-series" is being applied to all matching <p> tags but, all but the first one are being hidden.

Comment: Is the page this is happening on live? One alternative, is to just and an `}else{ jQuery(this).hide();}` to the code above and have it all done at once. It might get rid of whatever is conflicting.

Comment: @Aaron - I had one more question on that script.  Is there a way to also hide all but the first item, for each set of matching values?

Comment: Hmmm, if this doesn't work, open a new question. `$(this).html(letter + '<span class="hidden">'+jQuery(this).text().slice(1)+ '</span>');`

Comment: @Aaron - Thanks for your continued help.  This did not work.  It wrapped the span tags around all but the first letter, for each item.  New question posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041066/hide-all-but-first-matching-element

Comment: @Aaron - With the variables that are passed from the URL, the letters are working great but, is there a way to have a single variable pull pull all paragraphs starting with a number?  For example, domain.com/index.php?letter=0

Comment: `if(parseInt(jQuery(this).text().substr(0,1))) //do something else`

Answer (score 12):

If you'd like to use JavaScript to grab the `letter` from the URL query string, run a regular expression on `window.location.search`:

```
var letterParam = window.location.search.match(/letter=([a-z])/i), letter;

if (letterParam)
{
    letter = letterParam[1];
}
```

To match paragraphs starting with that letter, use the `charAt()` method in JavaScript strings:

```
if (letter)
{
    $('p').each(function()
    {
        if ($(this).text().charAt(0).toUpperCase() == 'B')
        {
            // Apply the CSS class or change the style...
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To hide the `<p>` tags whose text does not start with the letter `B`:

```
$('p').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().charAt(0).toUpperCase() != 'B';
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('p').hide().filter(function(){return $(this).text().match(/^b/i);}).show();
```

or indented

```
$('p').hide()
      .filter(
              function(){
                         return $(this).text().match(/^b/i);
                        }
             )
      .show();
```

*remove the `i` in the match if you want it to be case sensitive..*

and you can look at http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html on how to get the url parameters..

Comment: remove the i in the match if you want it to be case *in*sensitive..?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if its relevant here, but I am using this to style the first character.

```
$(".menu ul li.page_item a").each(function() {
var text = $(this).html();
var first = $('<span>'+text.charAt(0)+'</span>').addClass('caps');
$(this).html(text.substring(1)).prepend(first);
});
```

cheers!

Comment: Hey, I just got this working using two characters, so substr() instead of charAt(), but this was just what I needed.