# Hide All But First Matching Element

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery to sort through multiple paragraphs.  Currently I have it set to show only paragraphs that start with a current letter.  But now, I would like to consolidate further.  If the text between the paragraph tags has multiple instances, I would like all but the first hidden.

This is what I have so far but, it is not working.

```
var letter = '<?php  echo(strlen($_GET['letter']) == 1) ? $_GET['letter'] : ''; ?>'

function finish(){
    jQuery('p').each(function(){     
    if(jQuery(this).text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() == letter){
         jQuery(this).addClass('current-series');
         jQuery(this).html(letter + '<span class="hidden">'+jQuery(this).text().slice(1)+ '</span>');
    }
    else{ jQuery(this).hide();}
   })
}
```

**Update:**

Sorry guys, I know this is kind of hard to explain.  Here's a basic example:

- The selected letter is B
- The values returned are:

Ball

Ball

Ball

Boy

Brain

Bat

Bat

Each of these values is in a paragraph tag.
Is there a way to consolidate to this?

Ball

Boy

Brain

Bat

Comment: All but the first paragraph or the first letter? I thought you meant the actual first letter.

Comment: Ahh, you are better off doing it on the PHP/Mysql side of things when you get the data originally otherwise it gets messy.

Comment: I think I understand what you're looking for now. I updated my answer and the jsFiddle.

Comment: updated mine again too. Mine still hides paragraphs that don't start with the specified letter. I still say do this server side though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hide all but the first paragraph with that first letter:

EDIT: You can do the following messy solution.

```
function finish(){
    var found_first = [];
    jQuery('p').each(function(){     
    if(jQuery(this).text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() == letter){
    if(found_first[jQuery(this).text()] != true){
        jQuery(this).addClass('current-series');
        found_first[jQuery(this).text()] = true;
    }else{
        jQuery(this).hide();
    }
    }
    else{ jQuery(this).hide();}
   })

}
```

Comment: Aaron - You did it again.  Thank you so much.  Hopefully I'll be as skilled as you with Jquery some day :P

Comment: If you are selecting the data with MySQL you can select the data like this to get everything that begins with the specified letter and only unique names: 

`SELECT title FROM table WHERE title like 'a%' GROUP BY title;`

Comment: Yeah, I had thought about that but, unfortunately, mysql will not be available where the code is being applied.  Thanks though :)

Comment: How about doing the same thing but in PHP before it is sent to the browser?

Comment: If you have an array: `<?php $input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red"); $result = array_unique($input); ?>`. It removes the duplicate "green" and "red."

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I understand now.

**Try this:** http://jsfiddle.net/Upa3S/

```
    var letter = 'B';

    var array = [];  // Stores array of the content of paragraphs

    function finish(){
        jQuery('p').each(function(){

               // Cache reference to the paragraph
            $th = jQuery(this);
            if($th.text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() == letter) {

                    // Test if we've already stored the current content in array
                if(jQuery.inArray($th.text(), array) > -1) {
                       // If so, hide it
                    $th.addClass('hidden'); // You can do $th.hide() if you prefer
                } else {
                       // If not, put its content in the array
                     $th.addClass('current-series');
                    array.push($th.text());
                }
            } else {
                $th.hide();
            }
       })
    }

finish();​
```

---

Or using `.filter()`

http://jsfiddle.net/Fjj5d/

```
var letter = 'B';

var array = [];

function finish(){
    jQuery('p').filter(function(){
        $th = jQuery(this);
        if($th.text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() == letter && jQuery.inArray($th.text(), array) < 0 ) {
            array.push($th.text());
            $th.addClass('current-series');
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }).hide();
}
finish();
```

​

Comment: @Batfan - You're welcome. If you're interested, I worked up a little cleaner way using `.filter()`. No charge. ;o)